# Comment does not turn a part of css off

Tags: html, css

I seem to have a problem with understanding why I can't hide a part of my css in `<!-- -->`.

This is a bit of a problem since I'd like to have it prepared for later time, but for now it's useless. Tried searching but none of my research through Google or StackOverflow were of use.

The code I'd like to "comment-out" looks like this:

```
<!--h1 {
background: rgb(0, 191, 255); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't
                                support rgba */
background: rgba(0, 191, 255, .4);
width:50%;
text-align:right;
padding:0 20px 0 0;
}
.p1 {
background: rgb(0, 191, 255); /* Fall-back for browsers that don't
                                support rgba */
background: rgba(0, 191, 255, .3);
width:50%;
}-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To comment out CSS code you have to use `/*` (start) and `*/` (end):

```
/* h1 {
    background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
    background: rgba(0, 191, 255, .4);
    width:50%;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0 20px 0 0;
}
.p1 {
    background: rgb(0, 191, 255); 
    background: rgba(0, 191, 255, .3);
    width:50%;
} */
```

CSS doesn't support nestable comments, so you have to remove the inner comments, or you change the rules by prepending a not available ID or element (e.g. `#DISABLE` or `DISABLE`). So the rule is not matching on the DOM but get parsed by the browser.

> Comments begin with the characters `/*` and end with the characters `*/`. They may occur anywhere outside other tokens, and their contents have no influence on the rendering. Comments may not be nested.
>   **source:** https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#comments

The `<!--` (start) and `-->` (end) comment tags only comment-out HTML code, but not CSS code.

Comment: Care to elaborate: _or you change the rules by prepending a not available ID (e.g. #DISABLE)._

Comment: Thank you so much for not eating me alive!

That did solve my problem with the css code.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments), (emphasis mine):

> The `/* */` comment syntax is used for both single and multiline comments. There is ***no other way to specify comments in external style sheets***. However, when using the `<style>` element, you may use `<!-- -->` to hide CSS from older browsers, although ***this is not recommended***. As with most programming languages that use the `/* */` comment syntax, comments cannot be nested. In other words, the first instance of `*/` that follows an instance of `/*` closes the comment.

---

**What you should do**

If you are using an external stylesheet, use `/* */` to comment out section of your code (but keep in mind that comments cannot be nested). If you are just preparing CSS code that isn't going to be used later, then just don't include it in your page; instead, make a separate CSS file that is not linked from your HTML page to hold it there until it's ready.

Comment: Are you suggesting that he/she should wrap the `<style>` tag in `<!-- -->` ?

Comment: No. I emphasized "...this is not recommended".

Comment: Yes, but were you saying that he should wrap the `<style>` tag with the `<!-- -->` or the contents of the `<style>` tag (what he is doing now) ?

Comment: @Taurus I've removed the part of my answer that was probably causing confusion. I'm in no way saying use `<!-- -->` by any means.